# Show interstitial ads after click recyclerview item in fragment

Tags: android, admob

I have a custom recyclerview with many intent that go to new activity in fragment. The concept is like this, when user click the item on recyclerview, I want to display a interstitial ads before the new activity is appear. Then if user close the ads or ads failed to loaded, it automatically close the ads it and appear the next activity..how to do it ?

Remember, i use a fragment not activity.

This is my code so far

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ViewHolder> {


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;

        private TextView homeTitle, homeDesc;
        ImageView homeImage;

        private Context context;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            createInterstitial();
            context = itemView.getContext();
            homeTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.homeTitle);
            homeDesc = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.homeDesc);
            homeImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.homeImage);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    final Intent intent;
                    switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
                        case 0:
                            showInterstitial();
                            intent = new Intent(context, AllBlock.class);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            showInterstitial();
                            intent = new Intent(context, BasicBlock.class);
                            break;

                        default:
                            intent = new Intent(context, AllBlock.class);
                            break;
                    }
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }

        public void createInterstitial() {
            interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
            interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
            interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {

                }
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    loadInterstitial();
                }
            });
        }

        public void loadInterstitial() {
            AdRequest interstitialRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            interstitialAd.loadAd(interstitialRequest);
        }

        public void showInterstitial() {
            if (interstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                interstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                loadInterstitial();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have same problem but  i got it solution works perfect! here the code just add in you recylerview onclick method

```
 interstitial = new InterstitialAd(mCtx);
        interstitial.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                    interstitial.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Buddy, never publish your `keys`, even they are your test keys over the network.

Answer (score -1):

What you have to do is:

1) Extract specific view onClickListener. Let's call it `listener`.

2) Create a class of your own that implements `View.OnClickListener`.

3) Add the extracted view to your class listeners.

4) set the view's onClickListener to be your class.

5) Do your logic in the onClick of your class and then call the click events for the normal view.

Comment: i know this dumb request, but can you post with a code? i will apply u if it works :)

Comment: Once I have time I will do it, you have to use java reflection for some of the steps above. Upvote my answer please :)